# SharePoint 2013 incoming email (Reply and Forward mails creating new item)

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, incoming-email

I have setup incoming email in SharePoint 2013 Doc Lib and it's working. Whenever I send an email, it saves the attachment and email into Doc Lib properly with creating a folder.

But when I send the same email using reply or forward this also creates a new folder and saves the email and attachment in new folder. Is it possible that the reply or forward emails get saved into existing folder with the same name?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks